# Do PPAs freeze ever?

Tags: ppa

Say someone wants to get involved, but they want it to work properly for mass consumption first instead of a 'works for me' attitude.  Starting one before 12.04 goes stable could be difficult with all the packages changing quite rapidly(zeitgeist is a great example, but it's all for the better).

The question, is it safe to wait or does PPA creation freeze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no policy on when PPAs ever freeze or when you can create one, so it's really up to you.